# object will not return from prototype function

Tags: javascript

I instantiate an object like this: ( I mean to say object when I say array )

```
text_object = new SText( form_elements );
```

I call it like this for purposes of debug:

```
console.log('text_array in caller' + ( text_object.getArray().toSource() ) );
```

And the actual function looks like this:

```
SText.prototype.getArray = function( ) {
    console.log('text_array in getArray' + this.text_array.toSource() );
    return this.text_array;
};
```

The console.log shows the array in the the actual function but it is never returned:
Here is the log:

```
[15:16:44.160] text_array in getArray({url:"http://a.com", title:"a", tag:"a", domain:"a.com", path:"http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=a.com"})

[15:16:44.162] text_array in Caller({})
```

Comment: Is text_array declared by var text_array or by this.text_array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
console.log('text_array in caller' + text_object.getArray().toSource());
```